# Do we want a community blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

We've started [Step 2](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-will-our-blog-be-about) of getting a blog, defining our scope. If you want to make it happen, please participate in that discussion.

---

It's possible for a Stack Exchange site to [get it's own blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) provided we follow some steps to prove a couple things:

1. We want it
2. We can make it happen

So you know, the community will take part in posting and vetting the articles, and we'll try and nail down the following before we actually get it:

1. The Scope
2. Who will contribute (tentative, we're not locked in to only certain people contributing)
3. The schedule

As a starting point I really like the [Question of the Week](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/qotw25-introducing-qotw/) (QotW) concept on Security. I think it'd be a great starting point, taking the hottest question of the week and digging into the issue a bit deeper all in one post for easy consumption.

Remember the Blog can be more than a "greatest hits" of our questions/answers. We can also use it to share interesting news and opinions on happenings in the UX field or even design tips if we wanted.

Is this something we want? The next step would be to define what we want the blog to be about, first **I want to know if the support is there**. Please **vote to indicate your approval** and if you have any good suggestions, make them in an answer for when we start the next steps. We'll also need to know **who's willing to write** and **what we want to write about.**

Comment: Well, it can't be just generic "about UX" - we need to differentiate it from other publications.

Comment: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/539/should-ux-se-have-its-own-blog

Comment: @RogerAttrill I remmeber the thread, but thouht it was best to start anew; that attempt never materialized, and we've got more activity now

Comment: @dnbrv well the logical thing to do would be to focus it around *solving problems* similar to the main site but it can also include some *helpful* stuff that's not fit for the format of the main site. I didn't want to make the scope too specific before I gather attention though.

Comment: It could be a home for some of the less constructive questions that have been asked.

Comment: @ChrisF hmm, not as sure how to make that work, suggestions?

Comment: @BenBrocka - sorry I didn't see this comment before now - the idea would be that if something has value but doesn't fit in with the Q&A model it could be made into a blog post. It would have to be reposted though the Super User guys have suggested a mechanism for integrating the blog into the site so posts could be migrated (after suitable copy editing)

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few quick ideas for scope.

Directly supporting our core work:

- Highlighting the community's best work
- Calling attention to particular important issues in depth
- Revisiting and updating "core" or "classic" questions

Opinion-based content that doesn't fit our normal work but is interesting:

- Summarising and discussing latest developments and issues in the UX field
- Highlighting important meta.ux posts
- Working with other stackexchange communities (migration/collaboration)

Comment: Good ideas. We'll hammer out the scope more specifically in a more specific post too.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an idea for the community blog that could help to grow the audience, and draw attention to the site. 
A monthly UX angel service, with some kind of superhero theme.

- Choose a product (web site, software, smart phone, lava lamp, pen, car, space ship, etc)
- Do a UX review of the product (either focussed on a specific feature, or more broad)
- Make recommendations for improvements
- Do re-designs of certain components
- Write it all up in a beautiful blog post

Each article would probably require 4-5 UX'ers to participate. And there would need to be a style guide and/or writing guide to maintain consistency.
The value to the recipient of this review could be estimated at $1-5k, so being selected could become some kind of competition, which offers opportunities to draw attention to the site and grow the community.

This would be a lot of work! but would be really cool.

Comment: I can really see this working. Reviews could fit quite well into the traditional SE Q&A format, and it works with variable numbers of participants.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting idea from an old suggestion is [running our own usability studies](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/should-we-run-our-own-ux-studies). It's not something I'm set up to do myself, but if we could make it work it would be *awesome* to have blog posts sharing original research, especially answering questions from the site that don't already have research-backed answers.

I don't want to sign us up for anything too huge, but it'd be easy to conduct some simple A/B tests, perhaps using Usara or other online services if no one wants to donate their lab.

Comment: The university I went to has a usability lab on campus. I could see if they'd be willing to donate some of their time for non-profit/open source causes.

Comment: @AndrewShipe That'd be excellent! Next step (another meta post) we'll hammer out the details of how we'll work the specific ideas here

Answer (score 2):

Scope (what the blog will be about):

- [Usability Studies](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/should-we-run-our-own-ux-studies) (A/B Testing?)
- Question of the Week
- Add Items here

Who will be involved:

- Christofian
- Ben Brocka
- Andrew Shipe
- Add your name here

Schedule:

- Once a week, mayby more if we have some interesting usability studies set up.

Feel free to edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that a community blog is really needed. 
I admit that I'm not very active but from time to time I look at ux-stackexchange. And I don't really see the benefit for a community blog.