# Podcast dedicated to UX

Tags: discussion, community

Does anybody want to have a UX Stackexchange podcast? I think it'd be really cool, because UX is really, a living breathing field, and there'd be enough to talk about weekly (or at worst monthly), I'd be willing to do it. Plus, we'd be the first stackexchange site to have our own podcast (I think) (other than stackexchange itself).

Comment: No takers? Nobody wants to podcast?

Comment: I'm all for it! I'd be happy to assist with production and editing if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

There was an attempt recently to try to get a [UX.SE blog](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-will-our-blog-be-about) off the ground, but that hasn't yet taken off. I think if it's hard enough to get a blog going then a podcast is likely to be even trickier.

Perhaps a podcast could be wrapped up into the blog idea?

Comment: Yeah, that'd be great, I have a server sitting around (not a home server) collecting dust, so it could be used for that, all we need is a domain...uxblog.se would cost 30 bucks a year...uxblog.co would cost 10 and .info would cost 3

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm concerned, if you want to start a podcast, by all means start a podcast. Just go ahead and start a meta post with your proposed podcast topics and overview and see who else is interested, then go from there.

Comment: that was kind of the point of this post, to catch anybody who's interested, but I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

I did my Look and Feel podcast a few years ago, but my partner got busy getting a degree, so I haven't been able to pick it up again. I recently moved the inaugural episode to a new server and got rid of the bad first audio-only attempt.

I recorded two more episodes but never edited them and posted them (and might actually have lost half of the audio from one, still searching).

I'd be willing to offer to host episodes other people do at http://lookandfeelcast.com - I also have plans to publish the missing episodes there, but that requires me finding and editing the audio first, so don't hold your breath.