# Do YOU want to be part of our community blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

We've already got some [ideas for what our blog could be about.](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-will-our-blog-be-about) Now we need to know **who will participate in writing the blog**.

There are no reputation requirements, you don't have to be a moderator, you just need to be able to write for the blog and tentatively state how often you'll be able to commit to writing to the blog. All contributions to the blog will be **community edited**. Even if you can't write a blog post you can help edit, and all posts will be vetted by the community. **Please also add yourself to the [Trello Board for the UX.SE blog](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/969/trello-board-for-the-ux-se-blog) user list**.

If you're interested in participating, **answer this question with your tentative schedule and what you'd like to write about**. Give a rough time frame for how often you can contribute and which type of post(s) you want to write. There's no upper limit for contributors and there's no punishment if it turns out you can't help as often as you'd like, so if you think you can help, let us know.

So far we've got solid support for the following ideas:

- Question of the Week

  - Pick an interesting question from the past week and dive deeper into the issue.
- Case Studies

  - Original evaluations and/or walkthroughs of designs or redesigns.
- Original UX Research
- Commentary

  - Thoughts, opinions, and ramblings on recent UX literature/media (ideally both constructive and critical).
- External Resources

  - Posts about the UX community, events and people, including online information that has just been published (or good archives for people to look at), upcoming events, and informative print publications.

Got a better idea for a topic? Suggest it in [this question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-will-our-blog-be-about).
 - Book Reviews
   - Posts about relevant books including reviews, previews, suggested readings, etc.

Comment: Ben, you seem to be the one in charge of this, so could you create a chat room for the blog, so we can start getting to know each other and collaborating?

Comment: @Christofian you can meet people in the main chat room too, but I've created a room for this purpose: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3543/the-editing-room

Answer (score 5):

**Schedule**

I can tentatively commit to around one post a month, plus editing duty. I haven't done much blogging but I've been told I r gud riter.

**Content**

I'm up for just about any of the listed content, though **Question of the Week** is particularly appealing.

Answer (score 2):

I submit my name as a participator.

**Schedule**

I can participate a quality post every week right now. When work flares back up I would probably need to switch to once every two weeks.

**Content**

I'd be interested in writing or participating in contributing to any of the topics listed in the question at the time of this posting.

Comment: Since biweekly is [the worst word ever](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/biweekly) I'll assume you mean once every two weeks?

Comment: @BenBrocka I thought the context was enough, but I shall switch it to once a fortnight :) ... once every two weeks.

Comment: Are you on Trello? http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/970/7627

Comment: @BenBrocka Yeah, put myself in there already under my real name :) Dibbs = Dibbern.

Answer (score 2):

I would be happy to contribute content though I cannot promise a particular frequency. More attainable is providing editing services; I am a meticulous copy editor, and I would be happy to criticize, demean, and belittle the quality of posts others put their blood, sweat, and tears into (constructively, of course).

Answer (score 2):

### Schedule

I'll be happy to contribute once every two months.

### Content

Anything, though I would prefer original UX research ([I was the first person to come up with that idea](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/should-we-run-our-own-ux-studies) and post it on the meta, and I would like to see it to it's conclusion).

Answer (score 2):

### Schedule

I'd like to be able to contribute maybe once a month. Whether that's actually possible remains to be seen, but I'd like to try.

### Content

I'm very much an enthusiastic newbie to the field, so maybe that's a perspective that I can help with? I'm not really qualified to offer expert commentary on issues but I can do my best to research things.

Answer (score 2):

### Schedule

I could write one post a month

### Content

I'd be interested in doing a case study, question of the week, or commentary on articles I bump into. Also willing to help out editing.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to contribute and help edit.

**Schedule**

I'm happy to post every month or so, and review/edit on an ongoing basis.

**Content**

All of the proposed content areas sound great, and I could envision writing about any of them. Specifically, I would be good at handling certain Questions of the Week, Case Studies from my own work, Commentary (would LOVE to have somewhere to critique UX beyond 140 characters!) and share External Resources.

Comment: Great! Remember to sign up for the Trello Board: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/970/7627

Answer (score 1):

## Schedule

I commit to one post a month to make it quality work.

## Content

Real world examples of what happens when users don’t understand what to do. As inspiration I work as a SharePoint consultant with customer service responsibility and I hear a lot. I want it to be interesting and meaningful and get an insight of what the world outside has to offer.

Comment: Remember to sign up for the Trello Board: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/970/7627

Comment: @BenBrocka Signed up - and filed!

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to help edit.  I'm certainly not knowledgeable enough to write any posts myself, but I've been a "grammar nazi" since I learned grammar's existence and I greatly enjoy trimming the fat and enhancing readability of all things written.

Comment: Editing help is certainly welcome, we'll be brainstorming and editing in the chat room for this

Answer (score 1):

**Schedule**

I could write one post a month (flexible).

**Content**

I would specially enjoy writing about accessibility. Also, I wouldn't mind helping with editing (concept-wise, as English is not my first language).

Comment: Great to have an Accessibility person on board! Make sure to add your name/acconut to the Trello listhttp://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/970/7627

Answer (score 1):

**Schedule**

I can contribute to editing duties, given a reasonably predictable cycle.

For the time being, I am willing to contribute to editing duties. I can tentatively commit to writing something every two months, usually on original research in accessibility and gamification.

**Context**

I have a fair amount of experience in accessible web design and meta-accessibility concerns (e.g., management buy-in).

I'm an MA graduate, though not in UX; research and writing are certainly strengths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in writing an article, but still the topic haven't decided.  Let me know how to enroll as a blogger as well as editor.
thanks

Comment: You can sign up on trello and post your Trello name here http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/970/7627 and we'll get you added to the board. We don't have the blog live yet, waiting until we have a handful of finished articles to start with

Answer (score 0):

**Schedule**

Unfortunately, I cannot commit to posting on a regular basis. Best guess is that I would be able to post once a month or so.

**Content**

I'd focus on case studies from the field of conversion optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to write one post a month. I do about that for my blog anyway, so this isnt a hassle and i have some fairly interesting case studies too!