# Trello Board for the UX.SE blog

Tags: discussion, blog

If you're [planning to participate in our blog](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/952/do-you-want-to-be-part-of-our-community-blog) you should plan to join our [**Trello Board**](https://trello.com/board/ux-se-blog/4fc126cae25266c30814fc24) for the blog.

You'll need to be a member of the board to use it however, so please **post your Trello username/profile as a comment or add it to the list in my answer.** If you don't have a Trello account but are interested in participating in the blog at all, please [**Sign up for Trello**](https://trello.com/signup) and let me know your user name/profile link. Signing up is very easy, just give your name/email/password or Google account to sign up.

Here's an example of a working blog Trello Board from Programmers.SE:
[image]

We'll be using the board to brainstorm ideas, vote on them and track their progress all the way to the point of review (when we'll probably use a Google Document for collaborative editing) and publishing.

Comment: Just a little side information: Trello cards are oneboxed in chat.

Comment: @balpha oh really? Thanks, had no idea about that

Comment: I know it's 2014 now but is this still active?

Comment: @Pdxd contributions fell apart so it's basically on indefinite hiatus unless we get several people actively interested in it again

Answer (score 2):

Please edit your name and Trello profile in below so we can add you to the Trello board. Invites will be sent ASAP

Trello users for the Blog:

- [Ben Brocka](https://trello.com/benbrocka)
- [BJ Dibbern](https://trello.com/williamdibbern) (GotDibbs)
- [Myrddin Emrys](https://trello.com/myrddinemrys)
- [dhmholley](https://trello.com/dhmholley)
- [jimmybreckmckye](https://trello.com/jimmybreckmckye)
- [dnbrv](https://trello.com/dnbrv)
- [Andrew Shipe](https://trello.com/andrewshipe)
- [Dan Newman](https://trello.com/dannewman)
- [BennySkogberg](https://trello.com/bennyskogberg)
- [JonWalmsley](https://trello.com/jonwalmsley) (JonW)
- [Yisela Alvarez Trentini](https://trello.com/yiselaalvareztrentini)
- [ChrisF](https://trello.com/chrisforman) (I can proof-read/copy edit)
- [Roger Attrill](https://trello.com/rogerattrill)
- [Dynamic](https://trello.com/dynamic99) (Proof-Reader)
- [michaelsanford](https://trello.com/michaelsanford) (msanford)
- [Lisa Tweedie](https://trello.com/lisatweedie)
- [Ted Strauss](https://trello.com/tedstrauss)
- [Valentin Zwick](https://trello.com/valentinzwick) (vzwick)
- [Aadaam](https://trello.com/aadaam)
- [Kit Grose](https://trello.com/kitgrose)
- [Vitaly.Mijiritsky](https://trello.com/vitalymijiritsky)
- [Michael Lai](https://trello.com/plushzilla)
- [Charles Wesley](https://trello.com/_charleswesley)
- [Jørn E. Angeltveit](https://trello.com/jornangeltveit)
- [rk.](https://trello.com/rkx6)