# How can I participate in the User Experience Community Blog?

Tags: support, faq, blog

User Experience has a Community Blog and I would like to contribute.

- How can I contribute to this blog?
- How do I sign up?
- How does the publishing process work?

Comment: Ugh I'll have to finish this later, much more details soon

Answer (score 1):

### Sign Up

[**Sign up for Trello**](https://trello.com/) and [**add your name and Trello account to this list**](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/969/trello-board-for-the-ux-se-blog).

To sign up to be an author on the Wordpress blog itself, [email me (solve the Captcha to view)](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/d?k=01BRDSbiGwRT7HGMWNWHhkuA==&c=ZQqt1gUyQUDVqkJCwtCTFYcpIZVVL41rL7Gy4JvRl-0=) and let me know the username you want (all lower case, no spaces) and the email address you want me to sign up for your activation email.

### Brainstorming

### Using Trello

### What's on Topic?

Take a look at [What will our Blog be about?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-will-our-blog-be-about) to see the top rated topics for the blog, or just take an unclaimed Post Ideas card from Trello if you want a free topic. Generally the blog is for any form of constructive information sharing that doesn't fit in the main site's Q&A format.

### Important Links

[The Blog](http://ux.blogoverflow.com/)

[Trello Board](https://trello.com/board/ux-se-blog/4fc126cae25266c30814fc24)

[Blog Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3543/ux-blog)