# Let's get the blog in gear; call for contributors/status updates

Tags: discussion, blog

Our [Community Blog](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/952/do-you-want-to-be-part-of-our-community-blog) efforts faltered for a bit; we've got some good people working on some good ideas and a couple ideas ready to go, but it's not enough to start with. I'd like to get back that momentum we started with so we can push through and start this thing (that's the hardest part).

So what's going on? Update your status [on the Trello board](https://trello.com/board/ux-se-blog/4fc126cae25266c30814fc24). See a nice idea? Claim it and start writing or post a brand new idea and either write on it or leave it for others to possibly take. Not on Trello? [Join the Trello board for the UX blog](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/969/trello-board-for-the-ux-se-blog).

If you need help contributing at any step of the way, ask me here or drop a comment in the [UX Blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3543/ux-blog). Remember to Favorite the chatroom so you can easily rejoin if you plan to regularly contribute, or just stop in and brainstorm. Also check the [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) tagged questions for more info on the blog, who's contributing and what our topics will be. I'm particularly interested in [Case studies/walkthroughs](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/929/7627) and [Original UX Research](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/932/7627). If you want to help with that, let me know and I'll help you out with what you need to know.

While I have your attention, head on over to [the blog's login](http://ux.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin) to create your account (use your SE credentials please) and I can help you get that all ready for production. Just make an account, let me know and I'll grant you the Wordpress permissions you need to publish.

Let's make this work.

Comment: There were a few reasons I didn't manage to contribute as well as I liked - but one issue was that I never really understood the whole process behind writing and selecting a post for publication, start to finish.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye any specific questions? I was meaning to do a full explanation [here](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/997/how-can-i-participate-in-the-user-experience-community-blog) but I got busy, then forgot to complete it. Once you have a copy ready in google docs/whatever we'll get it into Wordpress where it'll be published. I added info on how to get into Wordpress above

Comment: well, how does a post start? Does there need to be consensus before something is written? Or do individuals just 'own' articles before submitting them to the group for review and publication?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye At the moment you can just pick an idea you want and start writing, but we've got some ideas posted and approved. The "review" step didn't seem very necessary since most posts get feedback in the idea/just starting stage. Generally whoever is writing "owns" the article but ideally you'd post a working draft somewhere were we can see progress (like google docs), and we need it in a google doc/etc to be able to edit + review it before it goes in the publishing bucket